# Basecamp 3 API - basic projects.json call

Tags: python, api, basecamp

I'm a Python user, beginner level. I'm trying to follow this instruction on Basecamp 3. Documentation: https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api

I've successfully gone through the authorization step and was able to retrieve the access token (which consists of 3 keys: access_token, expires_in and refresh_token.

Now i'm trying to pull some actual data from Basecamp, and the most basic call is to https://3.basecampapi.com/999999999/projects.json (with 99999999 being my account number, which I have).

The instruction has an example in curl: curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -H 'User-Agent: MyApp (yourname@example.com)' https://3.basecampapi.com/999999999/projects.json

But I cannot translate this to Python. I tried many methods of passing the keys to the header call but none works. Can anyone help me out?

Code:

```
url = "3.basecampapi.com/99999999/projects.json" 
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'User-Agent': 'MyApp (myemail@gmail.com)',
           'access_token': 'Access_Token_String',
           'expires_in': '1209600',
           'refresh_token': 'Refresh_token_string'}
result = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: what library are you using to make the request

Comment: I'm using requests library. I was able to use it for the whole authentication process without any problem.

Comment: great, let's see some code that you attempted

Comment: [code] 
url = "https://3.basecampapi.com/99999999/projects.json"

headers = {

    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    'User-Agent': 'MyApp (myemail@gmail.com)',

    'access_token': 'Access_Token_String',

    'expires_in': '1209600',

    'refresh_token': 'Refresh_token_string'

    }

result = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
[code]

Comment: you sure it’s a post request and not a get?

Comment: I'm not sure but I have tried POST as well as GET

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: you need to put https in front of your url in the request

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but posting an answer for anyone who happens to stumble upon this.

```
url = f'3.basecampapi.com/{PROJECT_ID}/projects.json'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'MyApp (myemail@gmail.com)',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           'Authorization': f'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Then view the output via `response.json()`